# make from a list the dictionary lists by key

Tags: python

I have a list:

```
['8C', '2C', 'QC', '5C', '7C', '3C', '6D', 'TD', 'TH', 'AS', 
 'QS', 'TS', 'JS', 'KS']
```

I need to get a dictionary something like this: (sorting is not important)

```
{'C': ['QC', '8C', '7C', '5C', '3C', '2C'], 
 'S': ['AS', 'KS', 'QS', 'JS', 'TS']
}
```

code:

```
def parse_flush(cards):
    cards = sort_by_color(cards)
    flush_dic = {}
    print str(cards)
    count = 0
    pos = 0
    last_index = 0
    for color in colors:
        for i, card in enumerate(cards):
            if card[1] == color:
                count += 1
                last_index = i+1
                if count == 1:
                    pos = i
        if count >= 5:
            flush_dic[color] = sort_high_to_low(cards[pos:last_index])
        count = 0
    return flush_dic
```

my code now looks like, it works but I do not like its length it is possible to make it shorter using python tricks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a very simple for loop:

```
>>> l = ['8C', '2C', 'QC', '5C', '7C', '3C', '6D', 'TD', 'TH', 'AS', 
...  'QS', 'TS', 'JS', 'KS']
>>> my_dict = {}
>>> for x in l:
...     my_dict.setdefault(x[-1],[]).append(x)
... 
>>> my_dict
{'S': ['AS', 'QS', 'TS', 'JS', 'KS'], 'H': ['TH'], 'C': ['8C', '2C', 'QC', '5C', '7C', '3C'], 'D': ['6D', 'TD']}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use simple [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to get the results you wanted

```
from collections import defaultdict
result = defaultdict(list)
for item in data:
    result[item[1]].append(item)
print result
```

**Output**

```
{'S': ['AS', 'QS', 'TS', 'JS', 'KS'],
 'H': ['TH'],
 'C': ['8C', '2C', 'QC', '5C', '7C', '3C'],
 'D': ['6D', 'TD']}
```

You can solve this, using [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.groupby) as well

```
data = ['8C', '2C', 'QC', '5C', '7C', '3C', '6D', 'TD', 'TH', 'AS', 'QS',
        'TS', 'JS', 'KS']

from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
keyFn = itemgetter(1)
print {k:list(grp) for k, grp in groupby(sorted(data, key = keyFn), keyFn)}
```

**Explanation**

`sorted` returns a sorted list of items, and it uses `keyFn` for sorting the data.

`groupby` accepts a sorted list and it groups the items based on the `keyFn`, in this case `keyFn` returns the second elements for each and every items and the result is as seen in the output.

Comment: can you explain `groupby(sorted(data, key = keyFn), keyFn` for me.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Please check the explanation I added in the answer and please let me know if it makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

```
data = ['8C', '2C', 'QC', '5C', '7C', '3C', '6D', 'TD', 'TH', 'AS', 'QS',
        'TS', 'JS', 'KS']

dic = {}
for i in data:
    try:
        dic[i[1]].append(i)
    except:
        dic[i[1]] = []
        dic[i[1]].append(i)

print dic
```

Output

```
{'S': ['AS', 'QS', 'TS', 'JS', 'KS'],
 'H': ['TH'],
 'C': ['8C', '2C', 'QC', '5C', '7C', '3C'],
 'D': ['6D', 'TD']}
```